# Stick sidebar on desktop, fixed at top on mobile

Tags: jquery

I need to use jQuery to create a sticky sidebar on desktop and fixed to top on mobile. (Not using css position:sticky.)

I am using window.matchMedia("(max-width: 601px)") to check the screen size. I want it to stop changing the top margin on screens smaller than 601px, however it does not.

For clarification: In the inspector when I

Here is the code snippet in Codepen, inspect and resize the window to see the issue in the responsive version when you scroll down:

https://codepen.io/AJco/pen/zYyMyLY

The 'sidebar' gets pushed away from the top.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) {

    //On small screens the sidebar should be fixed at the top. 


  } else {

    var offset = jQuery("#stickysidebar").offset();
    var topPadding = 15;

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

      if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        jQuery("#stickysidebar").stop().animate({
          marginTop: jQuery(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
      } else {
        jQuery("#stickysidebar").stop().animate({
          marginTop: 0
        });
      };
    });

  }
}
// Create a MediaQueryList object
const mmObj = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 601px)")

// Call the match function at run time:
myFunction(mmObj);

// Add the match function as a listener for state changes:
mmObj.addListener(myFunction)
```

```css
  #wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding 20px
}

#main {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%
}

#stickysidebar {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff
}

@media screen and (max-width:601px) {
  #wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #stickysidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
  }
  #main {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="stickysidebar">
    <H2>
      Sidebar
    </H2>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <h2>
      Main
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```